# Good phrase for a company being "self-centered"

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking to replace the phrase "self-centered" in the following example sentence:

> The board members did not care about anything but their profits. The company was polluting the environment, but barely noticed because it was so self-centered.

The problem is, a company doesn't really have a "self". All of the thesaurus entries here: https://thesaurus.yourdictionary.com/self-centered make use of either "self" or "ego", neither of which apply very well to a company. What's a good phrase to describe a company as the opposite of society-focused or philanthropic?

Comment: The premise of your question is based on a false assumption. There is no problem using *self* to refer to a company. As such, there is no better phrase than *self-centred* itself in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lexico (The Oxford Dictionaries) has entries for

> [**exploitative**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/exploitative)
>   ADJECTIVE
>   Making use of a situation or treating others unfairly in order to gain an advantage or benefit.
>   *Using corrupt means and intensely exploitative labour practices, they build up their own capital.*

and this word

> [**rapacious**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/rapacious)
>   ADJECTIVE
>   Aggressively greedy or grasping.
>   *They were revealed instead as rapacious asset-strippers.*

So the sentence becomes

> The company was polluting the environment, but barely noticed because it was so exploitative.

or

> The company was polluting the environment, but barely noticed because it was so rapacious.

Comment: The company in the example may indeed have been exploitative and rapacious.  But neither of these words means "self-centered".

Comment: @GEdgar the question is "What's a good phrase to describe a company as the opposite of society-focused or philanthropic?" During the post it moved on from the title.

Comment: Neither exploitative nor rapacious are synonyms of self-serving

Comment: @DJClayworth as already mentioned in the comments, the question does not ask for a synonym of "self-serving". Did you read them before repeating the first one?

Comment: Yes. The point is that neither "rapacious" nor "exploitative" make any sense in the example sentence. You don't "barely notice something" because you are rapacious, you "barely notice" the effect on others because you are focussed on yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**self-serving**

> Having concern for one's own welfare and interests before those of others; self-seeking. *The public had seen ‘nothing more than a self-serving determination to protect their vested interests’.*

Answer (score 0):

**There is nothing wrong with using self-centred of a company**

It's common to talk about the 'self' of an organization. [Here is an example referring to a company.](https://www.spiread.com/blog/avoid-the-trap-of-self-centered-marketing). [Companies are acknowledged to share many of the traits of human beings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_personhood) and it is normal to use adjectives about them in the same way as a person.

Comment: I agree. There is no better phrase than the one that the question seems to want to get away from for false reasons.

Comment: This does not answer the question and should be a comment.

Comment: it's what we call a 'frame challenge".

Comment: Yes, but I've previously answered a different question to that which was asked, on the grounds that it is a better solution than what was asked, and been downvoted. Yet now I answer the question that was asked, and get downvoted. Clearly OP didn't want to use "self-xxx" whatever the reason.